# Getting checked checkbox from database

Tags: php

I have checkboxes displayed in a loop with id's defined as check1, check2, check3 and so on

```
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check" id="check<?php 
echo $i; ?>">
```

Now I have two variables $chk1 and $chk2 both have values "check1" and "check2"
Is there anyway I could use an 'if' condition with OR gate within

```
<input class="single-checkbox"...>
```

to compare id with variable and return checked checkboxes 1 and 2.

Comment: If all your inputs have `check` as name (not the ID) the last one will overwrite the previous inputs.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i can change the name to check1, check2......

Comment: <input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check<?php 
echo $i; ?>" id="check<?php 
echo $i; ?>">

Comment: now is there a way I could use if  condition with OR gate?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="single-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="check<?php echo $i; ?> " id="check<?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

What I have realised is that you need to different names for all your checkboxes.Moreover you have not defined value for checkboxes.So now you will get different value for different checked boxes with different values.

**Response to OPs comment:**
In order to get the checkboxes pre checked of unchecked you will need to get it from your backend or your database which will be the values `true` or `false` corresponding to each index of your loop and put that in your checkbox checked attribute as follow:

```
<input checked="ValueFromDataBase" >
```

The checkbox will be checked or unchecked based on the value from your database.

Comment: Thanks I changed the names but I was wondering if i could put condition within the tag to return checked and unchecked checkboxes

Comment: Edited now you can check

Comment: This was somewhat helpful but since my checkboxes are in loop either all are checked or unchecked. I need to put a condition with checkbox name and variable :(

Comment: What is the condition you wanna keep them checked for ?

Comment: i have fetched id's from database as $b1 and $b2 (1 & 2). And have changed them to $b1="check1" and b2="check2". Now the checkboxes name are check1 check2 check3 and so on. The condition I need is if checkbox name or id is equal to $b1 or $b2 then checkbox checked else unchecked.

Comment: And how do you know which Id will have the check box checked